# String to DateTime Object

Tags: php, string, datetime

I'm new at String functions, so I need a complex substr and trim functions for this string:

```
Wed, 28 Dec 2011 13:04:30 GMT
```

String comes to me always with this format. I want to convert it to DateTime object. Anybody can help me?

Comment: have you tried this `$time = strtotime( $date );`

Comment: Why can't you just use datetime::createfromformat() - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php ?

Comment: strtotime function doesnt accept this format. datetime::createfromformat maybe can solve this situation. thanks for help, i am going to look it now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$dateString = 'Wed, 28 Dec 2011 13:04:30 GMT';
$dateTime = datetime::createfromformat('D, d M Y H:i:s e',$dateString);

echo $dateTime->format('d-M-Y H:i:s e');
```

Comment: thank you very much, i guess i can solve this problem with your solution. i am going to check and turn again.

Comment: The constructor of DateTime will accept this dateString without need to define a format.

Answer (score 17):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('Wed, 28 Dec 2011 13:04:30 GMT');
echo $date->format('r');
```

... prints:

```
Wed, 28 Dec 2011 13:04:30 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to take a date string and write that to the database as a date object using Doctrine:

Note: This is a form post example for Symfony 3 and 4.

```
$mynewdateobject = new \DateTime($request->request->get('mydatestring'));
```

Then you can write the object to the database or use it elsewhere in your code.